# Using a WRT54GL as both point-to-point link and access point

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, wrt54gl

Running **DD-WRT** on the **WRT54GL**, is it possible to connect an external directional antenna to one of the antenna connectors and have 1) a point-to-point Wi-Fi link with another WRT54GL (which has WAN connection) using SSID *A* and 2) a omnidirectional short range access point on SSID *B* using the stock antenna? Or will it just use the antennas arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it uses both antennas for everything, but you can create two concurrent SSIDs.This still sounds feasible, but you'll need a DD-WRT expert.